# how can I apply a function from vba taht was written for one cell to other cells in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that performs a calculation in one cell and I want to apply it to  a range of cells in my worksheet.

```
Dim standard As Variant
    standard = Range("G19") 'Retrieve the standard of the part'

If standard = "medium" Or standard = "heavy" Then
    Range("H19").Formula = "=-85*PI()*(D19/1000)^2+ 724.88*(D19/1000)"
ElseIf standard = "600/3" Then
    Range("H19").Formula = "=-85*PI()*(D19/1000)^2+ 724.88*(D19/1000)+0.98*(2*PI()*D19*C19 + 2*PI()*D19^2)"
```

Comment: Do you want to apply this process to a lot of cells and each time write the formula in the next cell to the right?

Comment: I want to apply the formula to the next cell and each time the formula is applied I want it to use the relevant D row value (i.e D19-D35).  So I want my code to test the conditions using a range of G column values (i.e. G19-G35) then print the calculated value for the formula in the relevant rows in column H.

Answer (score 0):

Please use loops if you want to perform a task on a range of cells

```
   `

    Sub LoopThroughCells()
    Dim standard As Variant, RowNo As Long, ColumnNo As Long
    'Assuming you want to apply formula in range G19:G35
 ColumnNo = 7  'Since G is 7th column
    For RowNo = 19 To 35 'Since Row range is 19 to 35
         
                standard = Cells(RowNo, ColumnNo) 'Retrieve the standard of the part'
                    If standard = "medium" Or standard = "heavy" Then
                        Cells(RowNo, ColumnNo).Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=-85*PI()*(RC[-4]/1000)^2+ 724.88*(RC[-4]/1000)" 'RC[-4] is Column D
                    ElseIf standard = "600/3" Then
                        Cells(RowNo, ColumnNo).Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=-85*PI()*(RC[-4]/1000)^2+ 724.88*(RC[-4]/1000)+0.98*(2*PI()*RC[-4]*RC[-5] + 2*PI()*RC[-4]^2)" 'RC[-5] is Column C
                    End If


Next RowNo
End Sub

 `
```

This code can be improved too if we have exact dataset or more clarification of task.

Comment: This makes no sense; you would be (potentially) repeatedly overwriting the contents of the same cell every turn around the loops.

Comment: ohh yes my mistake.. forgot to correct destination cell.

Comment: I want to apply the formula to the next cell and each time the formula is applied I want it to use the relevant D row value (i.e D19-D35). So I want my code to test the conditions using a range of G column values (i.e. G19-G35) then print the calculated values for the formula in the relevant rows in column H.

Comment: hello @xminx updated code as per your latest comments. Multiplication is Done with C19-C35 if you want fixed cell C19 then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to grasp the Excel object model and how the cells fit together. Every cell exists *relative* to the cells around it.

You can actually directly apply your formula to a range (`H2:H40` in the example). The relative references will allow the formulas to be different in each cell. Write the formula so it's correct for the first cell in the range.

```
Range("H2:H40").Formula = "=IF(OR(G2=""medium"",G2=""heavy"",G2=""600/3""),-85*PI()*(D2/1000)^2+ 724.88*(D2/1000)+IF(OR(G2=""medium"",G2=""heavy""),0,0.98*(2*PI()*D2*C2 + 2*PI()*D2^2)),"""")"
```

Since your formulas were very similar and the objective is to efficiently apply formulas to a range, I also incorporated your if statement into the formula like so:

```
If(<heavy, medium, 600/3>, <main formula> + If(<heavy, medium>, 0, <extra formula>), <empty cell>)
```

I would recommend you explicitly qualify your Range by putting a worksheet object in front of it.

Comment: Note that "600/3" is a string identifier not a calculation.

Comment: I am refraining from applying the formula directly because I am going to add other conditions to the existing conditions.

Comment: Thanks @Joffan! Adjusted that. To the OP, if your logic gets too complicated, you will need to loop through the cells: `For row = 2 To 40 ... Next row`. Using R1C1 notation in the formula is probably the easiest there. But be wary of logic that's unnecessarily complex and should be simplified. Placing logic in the formula is the ideal approach for calculations entirely dependent on surrounding cells. It reduces VBA, standardizes cells in a range, is less confusing to a user of your spreadsheet, is more maintainable, and forces you to be able to clearly state your logic.

Answer (score 0):

As an intermediate option, I'd suggest a user-defined function taking three values:

```
Function PartCalc(standard As String, _
                    Val1 As Double, Val2 As Double) As Double
' describe here what this function is calculating
Const pi As Double = 3.14159265358979
If standard = "medium" Or standard = "heavy" Then
    PartCalc = -85 * pi * (Val1 / 1000) ^ 2 + 724.88 * (Val1 / 1000)
ElseIf standard = "600/3" Then
    PartCalc = -85 * pi * (Val1 / 1000) ^ 2 + 724.88 * (Val1 / 1000) _
                + 0.98 * (2 * pi * Val1 * Val2 + 2 * pi * Val1 ^ 2)
Else
    PartCalc = -1 ' or some other dummy value
End If
End Function
```

Then the content of H19 would be `=PartCalc(G19,D19,C19)` (and of course copying this cell around would adjust the cells to the same relative positive around the chosen cell).

If you use this function, I recommend renaming "Val1" and "Val2" to something more descriptive, preferably with units, eg. `Flop_mm` and `Slop_mm`, and probably also rename `PartCalc` itself. Note that the use of the function name inside the routine is how the function returns a value, so all 4 instances of `PartCalc` would need to be updated to the same.